# Solution of Differential equation that provides infinitely many solutiions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''+y = 0$

$y(0) = 1, y(k) = 1 $

Find the value of   $k$   that the given problem has infinitely many solutions.

a) $\pi + 2n \pi$

b)  $2n \pi $

c) $\dfrac{\pi}{4} + 2n \pi $

d) $ \dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2n \pi $

**My work :**

The general solution is,

$y(t) = C_1 \cos t + C_2 \sin t $

$y(0)  = 1 $

$y = \cos t + C_2 \sin t $

$y(L) = 1 $

$\cos L + C_2 \sin L = 1$

$C_2 = \dfrac{1- \cos L }{\sin L }$

To get  $C_1 = 1$

$\cos L = 1 $

$ L = 2 k \pi , k \in N $

Is this approach correct? I have confusion with 4th option as well because,

$\dfrac{1- \cos L }{\sin L } = 1$

$\tan (L/2) = 1 $

$ L = \dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2n \pi $

Which option is the perfect match? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your first answer is correct**, i.e., $\boxed{L = k = 2n\pi } , n \in \Bbb Z$

As this will lead to,

$y(k) = 1\cdot\cos(2n\pi) + C_2\sin(2n\pi) = 1 + C_2 \cdot 0 = 1 $ which is **independent of $C_2$**.

---

The second answer is incorrect because that will be true only if $C_2 = 1$

(You have let $\frac{1-\cos L}{\sin L} = C_2 = 1$, so this doesn't have infinitely many solutions)

$y(k) = 1\cdot\cos(2n\pi + \frac\pi2) +C_2\sin(2n\pi + \frac\pi2)= 1 \cdot0 + C_2\cdot1 = C_2$

For $y(k) =1$, this will require $C_2= 1$

Comment: What a great way in explaining on why the second answer is incorrect. Admired by the way of approach. Thanks a million!

Comment: You're welcome! =)